# Is there a difference between calling a method from within a class' method code or on an instance of the class?

Tags: java, object, methods, call

I have a piece of code here and I'm not sure what a couple of commands do:

```
//this bit is the body of the main method
//lots of stuff omitted
project frame = new project();
frame.createGUI();

private void createGUI() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    panel = new JPanel();
}
```

So when `frame.createGUI();` is called, what happens with the two commands in `createGUI();`?
Are they

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
panel = new JPanel();
```

or

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.panel = new JPanel();
```

or is it something else entirely?
I'm quite new at Java, started year 12 Computer Science this year, but am a bit ahead of class.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every non static method in Java has an hidden parameter called `this`.  It's value is the object in front of the dot in the invocation.  Inside the body of methods, invocations of other methods implicitly have `this.` in front of them.  So does the use of variables, if they cannot be resolved locally.  If the `this` reference was explicit, your method would look like this:

```
private void createGUI(project this) {
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(this, EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.panel = new JPanel();
}
```

In the invocation of `createGUI` in your main method, what is really happening is something like this:

```
frame.createGUI(frame);
```

When running `createGUI` the `this` reference is a reference to `frame`.

Answer (score 1):

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Sets the operation that happens when the user closed the Window (JFrame). The method is for JFrame. If the class extends JFrame then `setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` is fine since it will call the method of JFrame if not then it should be `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` but this will work if project extends JFrame

```
panel = new JPanel();
```

This creates a new panel.

Answer (score 0):

`frame.createGUI();` means that your object `frame` which u defined a line above calls the method `createGUI()`

`setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` this means that when the user click  X button in the left top corner of the window will close the that window.

you can experiment a bit and delete `setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` from the `createGUI()` method and see what happens

if u want to learn more, look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Answer (score 0):

Your two alternatives are really one and the same. In both cases, you are calling methods of the `frame` object you created. From within a method of the class, you don't have to specifically say: `this.doSomethimg()` or `this.myField = 123`, you can just write `doSomething()` or `myField = 123`. From methods outside the class, you have to indicate for which instance you want the method called.

Comment: I can't upvote, not enough reputation, and the accepted answer was slightly clearer. But you helped too!